# Racket function flag arguments

Tags: function, lambda, lisp, racket, keyword-argument

Racket guide introduces functions with keyword arguments:

```
(define (F #:keyword argument) ...)
```

When we use it, we need to associate certain value with the argument:

```
(F #:keyword 'value)
```

But in the same guide there is an example of keyword argument **with no value**:

```
(struct posn (x y)
    #:transparent)
```

Is it possible to create such flag-like arguments for programmers, or it is clearly internal feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`struct` is not a function, it is a macro. You can define your own macros that uses keywords in the same way.

Comment: Thanks, I might think about macroses.